# How to perform de-normalization of last layer into labels in Keras, analogous to the preprocessing normalization layer (but inversed)?

Tags: keras, normalization, inverse, data-preprocessing

It is my understanding that Artificial Neural Networks work best on normalized data, ie typically inputs and outputs should have, ideally, a mean of 0 and a variance of 1 (and even, if possible, a "near gaussian", or at least, "well behaved", distribution).

Therefore, I have seen / written quite a few Keras-using scripts when I first do some feature-wise normalization of the predictors and labels. This is a pain, as this means the need to keep track of a number of mean and std values, applying them correctly later at inference, etc.

I found out recently that there is now out-of-the-box functionality for doing the predictors normalization in Keras in an "adaptable, not trainable" way, which is very convenient, as all the normalization information gets stored and used out-of-the-box in the network object: see: https://keras.io/guides/preprocessing_layers/ , https://keras.io/api/layers/preprocessing_layers/numerical/normalization/#normalization-class . This makes use / bookkeeping much simpler.

My question is: would it make sense / is there a simple way to similarly do in-Keras an "outputs de-normalization", i.e., assuming that the outputs from the network have mean 0 and variance 1, add an adaptable (adaptable not trainable; similar to the preprocessing normalization layer) layer that de-normalize these outputs into the correct mean and variance for each label?

I guess this is quite similar to the preprocessing normalization layer, except that what we would like is the "inverse transformation" of what would be obtained by applying the preprocessing normalization layer on the labels. I.e., when adapting the layer to labels, one gets a layer that "de-normalizes" a 0-mean 1-std distribution into a distribution with feature-wise mean and std corresponding to the labels.

I do not see some way to get this "inverse layer" or "de-normalization layer", am I missing something / is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The `normalization` layer has an [`invert`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Normalization#args) parameter:

> If True, this layer will apply the inverse transformation to its
> inputs: it would turn a normalized input back into its original form.

So, in theory you could use:

```
layer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(invert=True)
```

to de-normalize. Currently, this is [wrongly implemented](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/17047) and will not work (but seems like the bug is already fixed in the next keras version)

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I need :) . Then I will just adapt a layer to the labels, and "invert apply" it at the end of my network :) . Surprising that these layers are quite recent, these are simple transformations that make life much easier, but great they come into TF and Keras now :) .